# VIsual Source Safe to Plastic SCM migration

Tags: visual-studio-2010, version-control, visual-sourcesafe, plasticscm

I have a team of 3 developers including myself and currently we use VSS. We have run into issues with VSS when we needed to branch code in our development life cycle.

After going through documentation of various SCM, we have decided to switch to Plastic SCM.

We need to migrate from VSS to Plastic SCM where by all our change control history is also successfully migrated into the new PLastic SCM system. I am unable to find any documentation about migrating into Plastic with History.

Any inputs in this regard will be appreciated.

Thanks in advance for looking up my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no a direct app to migrate from Visual Source Safe to Plastic 4.0

You can do it in several steps:
1.- From VSS to Git: since there's no good way to migrate from VSS to Git format. You can find  apps like vss2git (http://code.google.com/p/vss2git/) to make this part.
2.- Export to fast-export
3.- fast-import to Plastic SCM v4

When you get the migration from VSS to Git, you can read this post, where we explain how you can import or export a repo from git:  http://codicesoftware.blogspot.com/2011/10/connecting-plastic-scm-to-github.html

Don't hesitate to contact us if you have any questions. Plastic SCM forum: http://www.plasticscm.net/